# Codeigniter Mysql database Error Number: 1267

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Today have Faced a strange config problem in Codeigniter. Yes, for that problem already we have solution
`Error Number: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)`
changing all table collation to `utf8_general_ci` will resolve this problem.
But,
Any one have idea why it perfectly worked at `$config['base_url'] ="localhost"` but not working when `$config['base_url'] =<public-ip>` ?

EDIT: Technically I solved the problem. But need theoretical explanations

Answer (score 0):

Your local computer and your server probably have default MySQL character set collation defined to them. My guess is that locally you're using utf8_general_ci and on the server - latin1_swedish_si.

Run `mysqld --help --verbose | grep collation-server` to see the difference between your two servers.

Comment: No separate server , in single system itself at localhost its working even my table collation are latin but if I call from IP (public IP) its throwing error.

Comment: If it's not the server, then how about the client? Do you use the exact same client version/os on both cases?

Comment: On a computer (same system not two comouters)I had faced this error. http://localhost not created issue but http://125.*** create problem